# How to handle cancelation of PXLongOperation

Tags: acumatica

I have a PXLongOperation in my code, I dont find a way how to know whether the user had cancelled the operation.

```
public PXAction<SomeFilter> someUpdate;
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Update")]
        public void SomeUpdate()
        {
            if (this.Base.Filter.Current == null)
                throw new PXException("Please choose val.");

            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this.Base, () =>
                           SomeOperation(this.Base.Filter.Current)                       
            );
        }

private void SomeOperation(SomeFilter filter)
{
   //how to know user cancelled operation or not?
}
```

Comment: If the worry is preventing the user from running the process again you can check for the processing running with something like this...  PXLongOperation.GetStatus(Base.UID) == PXLongRunStatus.InProcess

Comment: I need to know inside the thread whether the operation is cancelled or not. is there any option like the cancellation token in c#.

Comment: I believe the process should simply be aborted if the user clicks cancel. It might not be immediate when the user clicks cancel, but should cancel at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result of the PXLongOperation using the PXCustomInfo interface.
SetCustomInfo is used to set up the callback and PXLongRunStatus contains the result:

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, () =>
{
    PXLongOperation.SetCustomInfo(new PXLongOperationCallback());
    SomeOperation(Base.Filter.Current)
});

public class PXLongOperationCallback : IPXCustomInfo
{
    public void Complete(PXLongRunStatus status, PXGraph graph)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case PXLongRunStatus.Aborted:
                break;

            case PXLongRunStatus.Completed:
                break;

            case PXLongRunStatus.InProcess:
                break;

            case PXLongRunStatus.NotExists:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code example for error handling of callback operation:

```
public void Complete(PXLongRunStatus status, PXGraph graph)
{
    if (status == PXLongRunStatus.Completed && graph is MyGraph)
    {
        ((MyGraph)graph).RowSelected.AddHandler<MyDac>((sender, e) =>
        {
            MyDac row = e.Row as MyDac;

            if (row != null)
            {
               sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<MyDac.myField>(row, row.MyField, "Error Message");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to know inside the thread whether the operation is cancelled or not. is there any option like the cancellation token in c#.

Comment: Why do you need to know inside the thread? At the moment the thread is aborted it will call the Complete callback with status == PXLongRunStatus.Aborted. The graph context will be in PXGraph parameter, you can cast it from it's generic type to the specific Graph type you're using.

Comment: I added an error handling example as this is a common scenario for querying the result of a long running operation.

Comment: PXLongOperationCallback class can save the state, if you need to save information for use in the callback. You can add a parameterized constructor to pass that information from the long operation delegate body to the Complete callback.

Answer (score 1):

The delegate is invoked from a separate thread which will be aborted if the long operation is cancelled.

Comment: so you mean, framework will call Thread.Abort Method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b50fdsz(v=vs.110).aspx) which Raises a ThreadAbortException in the thread?

Comment: Exactly and the exception is swallowed. The API for this operation is publicly available through: PXLongOperation.AsyncAbort(MyGraph.UID)